# Firebase filter users who stopped using the app

Tags: ios, firebase-analytics

Our iOS camera app had a paid upfront model i.e., users has to purchase the app on app store. We have
changed it to an in app purchase. The users can download the app for free and try it out. After the user takes 20 
photos he/she will be prompted to buy and unless the user purchases he cannot use the app.

We are using firebase analytics to find out the distribution of users who have

1. paid upfront
2. still in free trial(haven't taken 20 photos)
3. bought an IAP
4. haven't paid after being prompted.

I have created a custom user property for this with 4 different values which represent the above 4 kinds of users.

Firebase says "Properties are effectively sticky event parameters that are automatically logged with every subsequent 
call to logEvent. After you set a user property value, it will be associated with every event logged afterwards"

If our user stops using the app after being prompted to buy and never opens the app again firebase will not update the
user property as there may not be any event afterwards. I can log an event just after setting this user property. But if the
user's internet is slow and he quits the app(app not in background) before event is logged I would still lose data.

Please tell me if my understanding is wrong.

I can filter the users who have been prompted by screen_view event. If I can find out users who stopped using the app,
then users who have been prompted to pay and stopped using the app will be the ones who didn't pay.

Is there a way to filter users who have stopped using the app in firebase?

Answer (score 0):

The event after the promotion of the user property will work. Firebase does not fire events to analytics on every hit. It collects a group of events+timestamps that needs to be fired and fire those events in a bundle after the app is closed(goes to background). This is to preserve device battery and improve performance. So slow internet will not cause the event to not fire. Just set the event right after you set the user property.